# Jersey helloworld sample get 404 code from browser

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jersey_helloworld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jerseyhello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jerseyhello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is all the jar in the web-inf/lib and I have added them to build path.
[image]

Below is my HelloWorld code.

```
package com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello World RESTful Jersey!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</hello>";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</title>" + "<body><h1>" + "Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }

}
```

At last, I called this web service from firefox like below.

```
http://localhost:8080/jersey_helloworld/rest/helloworld
```

Then HTTP Status 404 - Not Found was printed. And nothing error message was printed in the eclipse console.

Comment: Please make sure all your jars are packaged in the war.

Comment: yes. I copied all the jars to lib

Comment: Is your rest service running successfully?

Comment: How to check whether my rest service is running successfully? I just visited http://localhost:8080/jersey_helloworld/rest/helloworld, but failed

Comment: are you deploying through ide or dropping the war in the tomcat folder ?

Comment: ide, my webapp deployment is correct definitely . I can access the static file under web root.localhost:8080/jersey_helloworld/1.txt

Comment: Ca you please confirm if you have added  the mapping for jars in the deployment assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used:

1) following jars:

[image]

2) web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseyhello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jerseyhello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

3) your source code without any modification.

and result is:

[image]

Comment: thanks. I got it. And I have found the root cause. It's because my classes folder is jerseyhelloworld/build in eclipse, the correct one should be jerseyhelloworld/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes. But my question is why it does not report the classnotfound exception .

Comment: Your class `HelloWorld` is supposed to be loaded by `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer`. We do not mention the name our class in `web.xml`, we only specify `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` to instruct from where classes should be loaded. Since we do not specify the name of our class, `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` does nor throw 'ClassNotFoundException`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `@Path` annotation to every method to specify different paths. Now, you are calling just `/helloworld` but there is no method associated to that path.

For example, for the first method try to do this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/plainText")
public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello World RESTful Jersey!";
}
```

and call it this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/jersey_helloworld/rest/helloworld/plainText
```

Comment: if you are using eclipse, go to the properties of your project -> Web Project Settings and check the name of the context root. I see you are calling jersey_helloworld but this is your display name.

Comment: there is no need to add path to the method as they all produce different media type and jersey should to able to resolve it to one method

Comment: I think my context root is right since I can visit any static file under this project like http://localhost:8080/jersey_helloworld/1.txt